# CAShapeLayer with UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, drawing, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I wanted to display a triangle shaped view in a UITableView cell like this.

[image]

I managed to accomplish this using the blow code.

```
import UIKit

class TriangleView: UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let width = self.layer.frame.width
        let height = self.layer.frame.height

        let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 0, 0)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, width, 0)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, height)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, 0)
        CGPathCloseSubpath(path)

        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.frame = self.layer.bounds
        mask.path = path

        self.layer.mask = mask

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.frame = self.bounds
        shape.path = path
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

        self.layer.insertSublayer(shape, atIndex: 0)
    }
}
```

While I was searching how to create shapes in UIViews, I discovered that you could use `UIBezierPath` to do the same. So I tried replicating the same thing using `UIBezierPath`.

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: width, y: 0))
path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: height))
path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
path.closePath()

let mask = CAShapeLayer()
mask.frame = self.bounds
mask.path = path.CGPath

self.layer.mask = mask

let shape = CAShapeLayer()
shape.frame = self.bounds
shape.path = path.CGPath
shape.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

self.layer.insertSublayer(shape, atIndex: 0)
```

But this simply does't work. No shape is getting displayed.

Do I need to do anything extra in order to get this working?

Comment: You have to create a new context to draw.

Answer (score 9):

You're making this harder than it needs to be. You only need to add a shape layer with a path, and set the `fillColor` of that layer. The main reason your code doesn't work though, is because you're using `moveToPoint` for all you lines instead of `addLineToPoint` for all but the first one.

```
class TriangleView: UIView {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: frame.size.width, y: 0))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: frame.size.height))
        path.closePath()

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.frame = self.bounds
        shape.path = path.CGPath
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(shape)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can the second layer be replaced with a simple `self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()`?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - I thought that like the OP you were adding a mask and inserting an identical sublayer, when a mask and backgroundColor would suffice

Comment: How can I use a gradient color rather a simple color as shapes fillcolor @rdelmar

Answer (score 3):

The problem should be the mask on layer and the color of shape.
The following code work for me.

```
class TriangleView: UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let width:CGFloat = bounds.width/9
        let height:CGFloat = bounds.width/9

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.moveToPoint(bounds.origin)
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: width, y: bounds.origin.y))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x, y: height))
        // closePath will connect back to start point
        path.closePath()

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path.CGPath
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor

        self.layer.insertSublayer(shape, atIndex: 0)

        // Setting text margin
        textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, width, 8, 0)
    }
}
```